# Server error redirection using htaccess is not working

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I want to create custom pages on my server for error handling and redirection, I have created one and generate 500 error using PHP but the redirection didn't work for me, My htaccess code is given below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^error-500.html$ error-500.php [NC] 
ErrorDocument 500 /error-500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error-500.html
```

In my PHP index.php I have added the following to generate 500 error, I have also checked with 404 error.

[image]

Note:  I have also added the following in Additional nginx directives of plesk but that redirection also did not work for me.

```
error_page 404 /error-500.html;
```

I would apprciate help for making my redirection work on a 500 error.

Comment: Why don't you simply do:
ErrorDocument 500 /error-500.php
and remove rewrite instructions as unneeded?

Comment: My site need all urs as .html. But that php to html rewrite is not preventing error redirection

Comment: Try to put rewrite rules after errordocument rules, and try [L] instead of [NC]